# Assign a negative unsigned int to a double in C

Tags: c, double, standards, variable-assignment, unsigned-integer

Does anyone know what part of the C spec describes the behavior that follows:

The following code snippet reproduces the situation (note that there is some boilerplate code in order to avoid certain compilation optimizations that would not cause the issue):

```
volatile int zero = 0;
unsigned int someint = 20;
if(zero == 1)
{
    someint += 1;
}
double x = -someint;
```

The compiler (*clang 3.5.0*, but *gcc 4.9.1* emits something similar) emitted the following for the last assignment:

```
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc]   <-- move someint in eax
neg    eax
mov    ecx,eax
cvtsi2sd xmm0,rcx
movsd  QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],xmm0
```

The interesting thing is that the two's complement negation (*neg*) is performed on a dword (*eax*) but the dword to double precision conversion (*cvtsi2sd*) is performed on a qword (*rcx*) whose lower 32 bits are the negative number -20 (mov ecx,eax) and whose higher 32 bits are all 0.
Since *eax* was not sign extended into *rcx*, *rcx* now holds a positive number, which ends up in *x* after the conversion.

On the other hand, if *someint* is casted to an *int* in the assignment, the dword to double precision conversion (*cvtsi2sd*) is performed on a dword (*ecx*) and hence the end result is the expected -20 in *x*.

Comment: What's the question? Sounds correct to me. `unsigned int x = -20`, converted to double, should be `4294967276.0`.

Comment: The expression `-someint` applies the unary `-` operator to the `unsigned int` value of `someint`. The result is an `unsigned int`, which is then implicitly converted to `double`. It's equivalent to `unsigned int tmp = -someint; double x = tmp;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "negative unsigned int". Unsigned int is always positive. Your -someint produces the value 0 if someint = 0, and UINT_MAX + 1 - someint otherwise according to the C rules. Use instead

```
double x = - (double) someint;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a "negative" `double` from an `unsigned int` you must first negate as an `integer` and `cast` to `double` (either by bitwise negation or changing signs):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    unsigned int x = 44231;     /* unsigned number              */
    int i = ~x;                 /* bitwise not gives negative   */
    double d = (double)i;       /* cast to double               */

    double e = (double)(int)~x; /* all in one set of casts      */

    printf ("\n unsigned x  =  %u\n", x);
    printf (" int i       =  ~(x)       =  %d\n", i);
    printf (" double d    =  (double)i  =  %lf\n\n", d);
    printf (" double e    =   (double)(int)~(x)  =  %lf\n\n", e);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/neguint2dbl

unsigned x  =  44231
int i       =  ~(x)       =  -44232
double d    =  (double)i  =  -44232.000000

double e    =   (double)(int)~(x)  =  -44232.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me you need to typecast your someint in double before assigning it to x.